# Partition over when order by may be null

Tags: t-sql, left-join, partitioning

Using TSQL 2008 R2,  I have a table of demographic data and a table of activities. I want to Left join the tables so I get all the Demo data and whatever activity exists. Furthermore, I want to assign a row number to each row so that if there is more than one activity row for any given person in the demographic table, the rows are numbered such that the most recent is Row 1.

I have:

```
Select D.*, A.ActivityDate, A.ActivityType, A.PersonId,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By A.PersonId Order by A.ActivityDate DESC) as RowNumber
From Demo D
Left Join Activity A
On D.PersonId = A.PersonID
```

Since not all people in the Demo table will have activities, the Left Join on Activity will show A.ActivityDate as Null.

How does this effect the Order By clause, and how do I make sure I get all the data I need?

Thanks to all who help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a coalesce in your order by? This would give those records that are null, a default.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By A.PersonId Order by COALESACE(A.ActivityDate, CAST('1/1/1900 00:00:00' AS date)) DESC) as RowNumber
```

Which would make the output of your query look like such:

```
Select D.*, A.ActivityDate, A.ActivityType, A.PersonId,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By A.PersonId Order by COALESACE(A.ActivityDate, CAST('1/1/1900 00:00:00' AS date)) DESC) as RowNumber
From Demo D
Left Join Activity A
On D.PersonId = A.PersonID
```

As far as your question

> "How does this effect the Order By clause, and how do I make sure I
>   get all the data I need?"

This will force the records with nulls to be ordered to the bottom of your list (since it's descending) since they have a default value of 1/1/1900 making the **assumption** that your column is a datetime.

Comment: Thank you, Brent. That was an interesting suggestion and I will pursue it.

Answer (score 0):

partition by the left so you have a partition value

```
Partition By D.PersonId Order by A.ActivityDate DESC
```

test for yourself

```
Select D.*, A.ActivityDate, A.ActivityType, A.PersonId
From Demo D
Left Join Activity A
On D.PersonId = A.PersonID 
order by D.PersonId, A.ActivityDate DESC

Select D.*, A.ActivityDate, A.ActivityType, A.PersonId
From Demo D
Left Join Activity A
On D.PersonId = A.PersonID 
order by D.PersonId, A.ActivityDate ASC
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to reply, Blam, but exchanging ASC for DESC doesn't elucidate anything.

Comment: It did not elucidate how null sorts?